# Compress using tar without saving full path

Tags: backup, tar

I would like to compress backup directory, but not saving all path of data.
After unpack i want have only destination directory.
How Can I do this?

This command save all path:

```
$tar -czf /home/user/backup/www_`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tar.gz /home/user/www

$ tar -xvf redmine_www_2018-03-02.tar.gz 
home/user/www/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been answered a million times:

```
tar -czf /home/user/backup/www_`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tar.gz -C /home/user/www .
```

Comment: And since it’s been answered a million times, the appropriate reaction isn’t to add yet another answer, but to find an appropriate duplicate and vote for it.

Comment: Well you're right, we should start to educate and stop with the spoiling...